# A sheaf is locally constant iff the etale space is a covering

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, covering-spaces, locally-connected

Let $X$ be a locally connected space a sheaf $F$ on $X$ is called locally constant whenever each $x\in X$ has a basis of open neighbourhoods$N_x$ and if $U,V \in N_x$ such that $U$ is a subset of $V$ then the restriction map $FV\rightarrow FU$ is a bijection.

How can I show that the sheaf $F$ is locally constant iff the associated etale space over $X$ is a covering?

Comment: Well, for every $x \in X$ there is an open neighbourhood $W$ such that the covering map over $W$ is just a disjoint union of copies of $W$. Then the connected open subsets of $W$ form the basis you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, So sorry I forgot to put iff instead of if

Comment: I edited. Sorry again

Comment: The other direction is basically the same. For every $x \in X$ choose some $U$ in your basis of open neighbourhoods, and then over that $U$ the espace étalé is just a disjoint union of copies of $U$. You should probably use the construction in terms of topologising the disjoint union of stalks rather than a big complicated colimit. I'm sure it's straightforward, just tedious.